# How do I interpret the __transition__ property that D3 attaches to DOM elements as part of a transition?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I implemented a chained transition using the transition.transition() pattern (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#transition).

The __transition__ property after the first transition is scheduled:

```
{"4":{"tween":{},"time":1410878734661,"delay":0,"duration":1500},"active":0,"count":1}
```

The __transition__ property after the second transition is scheduled:

```
{"4":{"tween":{},"time":1410878734661,"delay":0,"duration":1500},"5":{"tween":{},"time":1410878734661,"delay":1500,"duration":500},"active":0,"count":2}
```

Is "4" the id associated with both parts of this chained transition? Does active:0 indicate there are no actively running transitions? Does the count property indicate the number of transitions scheduled?

Thanks in advance!

```
var t0 = text.transition().delay(0).duration(1500) //first transition
var t1 = t0.transition().ease("bounce").duration(500) //second transition
```

Answer (score 0):

The numbers in your object are indeed the ID of the transitions. `active` holds the ID of the active transition and `count` the total number of transitions.

More information in [the source](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/transition/transition.js).